# VBA convert range to array and format date

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with a conversion to array in VBA :

```
Dim list As Range
Set list = Range(series, series.End(xlDown))
list.Select
Dim table() As Variant
Set table = list.value
```

My understanding is that `value` returns an array right ? I don't get why VBA tells me that I `"can't assign to array"`.

My `list` range looks like that in Excel at the `Select`, and i aim at having that as an array so that I can format my dates using something like `Format(table.Rows(i).Columns(1).value, "yyyy-mm-dd")`, looping on my table.

```
02-Sep-09   1.00
18-Sep-09   1.00
16-Oct-09   1.00
20-Nov-09   1.00
18-Dec-09   1.00
19-Mar-10   1.00
18-Jun-10   1.00
```

By the way, is it possible to modify the table in place ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problem here.

**Problem 1**

```
Set table = list.value
```

table is not an object so you cannot set it.  Try:

```
table = list.value
```

**Problem 2**

series is a VBA keyword associated with charts.  Please pick a name, such as MyWSTable, which means nothing to VBA.

**Problem 3**

A worksheet name is not itself a range.  Try:

```
Dim Table() As Variant
Table = Names("MyWSTable").RefersToRange.Value
```

Note: you do not need variable list nor do you need to select the range.

**Answer to formatting question**

The following code will reformat your dates:

```
For inxrow = 1 To UBound(Table, 1)
  For inxcol = 1 To UBound(Table, 2)
    Table(inxrow, 1) = "ddd d mmm yyyyy"
    Table(inxrow, 2) = ""
  Next
Next

Names("MyWSTable").RefersToRange.NumberFormat = Table
```

Comment: Extra warning.  Moving dates from a worksheet to an array then back again is not safe unless you use American dates.  The move from sheet to array is OK.  But, on the move back, if the date can be interpreted as an American date, it will be.  So "16 Oct 2009" will remain unchanged because "16/10/2009" is not a valid American date but "2 Sep 2009" will become "9 Feb 2009".  You **must** convert dates to unambiguous strings before copying the array to or back to the worksheet.

Comment: this is not true if you use the numeric `Date` data type; in that case, the date is represented as an IEEE double.  And how did you choose the dates that are the birthdays of my father and mother in law?

Comment: I discovered this problem some years ago when I first tried Excel VBA.  It was a while before I realised that many of the dates in my database were wrong and it then took me a lot of experimentation before I identified the cause.  I had started with Date variables but I tried other formats but the only reliable method I found of placing a date in a cell was to use strings in the format ddmmyyyy.  I have kept the same approach ever since so it is possible that this error was fixed in a later version of Excel without me noticing.  You will have to ask jerome G where he got the dates.

Comment: I omitted an "m" from the format string in my previous comment.  I meant "ddmmmyyyy".  For example: 2Dec2011.

Comment: SQL (at least JET SQL) requires American date format for date literals, which would explain why database dates were incorrect, but if you have a VBA Date-type value, the value is purely numeric and *does not have a culture-specific format.*  The culture specific format only comes into play when you are converting to a string (e.g., for display) or from a string (e.g., parsing input).

Comment: Looking through my diaries I see that I encountered this problem in mid 2003. Presumably, this was pre-Excel 2003. I cannot duplicate the problem today so either this is bug that has been fixed or it was my programming error. Normally, I try out every comment or answer before I write it. I made the mistake of not checking on this occasion because I was sure I encountered a posting (which I cannot now find) about this issue within the last month. In future, I will keep to my rule of checking everything. I will also revisit all my date processing code to see if I can simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your select: `list.Select`

To be sure you won't get errors when assigning a range to an array, you'd better declare your array as a variant:

```
Dim table As Variant
table = Range(series, series.End(xlDown)).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

That error message is popping because you are using **SET** to fill the array.  Drop the SET and it should load.

You can fil directly the array as follows:

```
Dim table() As Variant
table=Range(series, series.End(xlDown))
```

Omiting the **Select** step makes your code safer and faster.

Unfortunately, you can not load the values directly as dates.  You will have to loop throu every item of the array and turn them into date.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this incorrectly.  You should use the `NumberFormat` property of the range to specify the display format.  Something like this:

```
Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```